# How to create layered panes

Tags: java

I am trying to create layered panes for my java game and in the few examples I've seen getLayeredPane has been used, but not imported. When I try and do the same I get a "cannot find symbol" error, which I believe normally means that something has not been imported. What am I doing wrong here?

```
package game.backbone;

import game.background.Background;
import game.character.DrawCha;
import game.character.MoveCha;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;

public class Window {
 private DrawCha cha;
 private MoveCha move;
 private JFrame frame;
 private Background bg;
 public static int SIZE;
 public static int w, h;

 public void createWindow(String title,int height) {
  bg = new Background();
  cha = new DrawCha();
  move = new MoveCha();
  frame = new JFrame();

  JLayeredPane lp = new getLayeredPane();

  h = height;
  w = height;

  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setSize(w, h);
  frame.setTitle(title);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setFocusable(true);

  frame.addKeyListener(move);

  lp.add(cha, new Integer(2));
  lp.add(bg, new Integer(1));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `JLayeredPane lp = new getLayeredPane();` is incorrect.You are calling new on a method.
Modify it`JLayeredPane lp = new JLayeredPane();`

```
public void createWindow(String title, int height) {
    bg = new Background();
    cha = new DrawCha();
    move = new MoveCha();
    frame = new JFrame();

    JLayeredPane lp = new JLayeredPane();

    h = height;
    w = height;

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.addKeyListener(move);

    lp.add(cha, new Integer(2));
    lp.add(bg, new Integer(1));
    frame.add(lp);
    frame.setSize(w, h);
    frame.setTitle(title);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Also check if your DrawCha and Background classes extend JInternalFrame.You can have something like

```
class DrawCha extends JInternalFrame {
 public DrawCha() {
      setBounds(50, 50, 100, 100);
      setResizable(true);
      setClosable(true);
      setMaximizable(true);
      setTitle("DrawCha");
      setVisible(true);
    }
```

}

Comment: so a JInternalFrame acts like a window inside a window? I don't really want that. also DrawCha and Background already extend JPanel

Comment: Also it does not work, it runs but everything is just white

Comment: If you are extending JPanel,try setting a background color to see the Panel,else if will have the default color of the Frame and you wont be able to differentiate.Something like  the below code,inside your DrawCha Constructor:                                                                 setBounds(50, 50, 100, 100);
      setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
      setVisible(true);

Comment: Thank you for your help, but in doing more research I found out that I would be better off using one JPanel and painting images onto it.